# NIntegrate performance improvement

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

Assuming a beam under infinitesimal strains, elastic constitutive law that has the following geometry and material constants:

```
b = 50;(*thickness mm *)
h = 100;(*heigth mm *)
L = 1000;(*length mm*)
young = 205000 (*steel elastic modulus N/mm^2*);
nu = 0.3;
lambda = young nu/((1 + nu) (1 - 2 nu));
mu = young (2 (1 + nu))
```

it's displacement can be found through an energy minimization. Consider a generic polynomial displacement field of third degree as defined below

```
(*Generates a generic dispacement field*)
p = 3; (*polinomial order*)
genericdisplacement = Flatten[Table[x^i  y^j  z^k, {i, 0, p}, {j, 0, p}, {k, 0, p}]];
ux = Table[{genericdisplacement[[i]], 0, 0}, {i, 1,Length[genericdisplacement]}];
uy = Table[{0, genericdisplacement[[i]], 0}, {i, 1,Length[genericdisplacement]}];
uz = Table[{0, 0, genericdisplacement[[i]]}, {i, 1,Length[genericdisplacement]}];
displacemet = N[Join[ux, uy, uz]];
Length[displacemet]
```

restricting the field in order to respect the boundary conditions i.e. a clamped beam in it's left side

```
(*Impose boundary conditions*)
For[i = Length[displacemet], i >= 1, i--,
 If[(displacemet[[i, 1]] /. {x -> 0}) != 0,displacemet = Delete[displacemet, i], , displacemet = Delete[displacemet, i] ];
 If[(displacemet[[i, 2]] /. {x -> 0}) != 0,displacemet = Delete[displacemet, i], ,displacemet = Delete[displacemet, i] ];
 If[(displacemet[[i, 3]] /. {x -> 0}) != 0,displacemet = Delete[displacemet, i], ,displacemet = Delete[displacemet, i] ];
 ]
Length[displacemet]
```

and finally, integrating the stiffness matrix, the load vector and solving the linear system, we can find the `solution`.

```
(*Generates the stiffnes matrix, the load vector and solve the linear system*) 
displacementgradient = Table[Transpose[{D[displacemet[[i]], x], D[displacemet[[i]], y], D[displacemet[[i]], z]}], {i, 1, Length[displacemet]}];
strain =Table[(displacementgradient[[i]]+Transpose[displacementgradient[[i]]])/2, {i,1,Length[displacementgradient]}];
stresstensor = Table[lambda Tr[strain[[i]]] IdentityMatrix[3] +2. mu strain[[i]], {i, 1, Length[strain]}];
energy = Table[Tr[strain[[i]].stresstensor[[j]] ], {i, 1, Length[strain]}, {j, 1,Length[strain]}];
volumeload = Table[{0., 0., 0.}.displacemet[[i]], {i, 1, Length[displacemet]}];
faceload = Table[{0, 0., -2.}.displacemet[[i]] /. x -> L, {i, 1,Length[displacemet]}];
{time, loadvector} = NIntegrate[volumeload, {x, 0, L}, {y, -b/2, b/2}, {z, -h/2, h/2}] +Integrate[faceload, {y, -b/2, b/2}, {z, -h/2, h/2}]//AbsoluteTiming;
Print["Volume Load Integration = ", time, " seconds"];
{time, stiffnessmatrix} = Table[NIntegrate[N[energy[[i, j]]], {x, 0, L}, {y, -b/2, b/2}, {z, -h/2,h/2}], {i, 1,Length[energy]}, {j, 1, Length[energy]}] // AbsoluteTiming;
Print["Energy Integration = ", time, " seconds"];
solution = LinearSolve[stiffnessmatrix, loadvector];
approxsolution = Sum[displacemet[[i]] solution[[i]], {i,Length[displacemet]}];
```

The problem i'm having is that the integration of the `energy` is taking too long (hours). I understand that there is a large number of polinomyals to be integrated ( 144 x 144 = 20736), but does anyone knows how to speed things up?

Comment: If they're polynomials, you can get the coefficients and basically take the dot product with the power rule applied to the monomials.

Comment: In this case, since you know what kind of functions may appear, I think you can gain a lot of speed by making the integration formulæ yourself. Then you can also treat the special cases more efficiently, e.g. the terms that are odd in y or z will automatically become zero because of the integration range.

Comment: @Michael E2 can you give more details on how to find this coefficients?

Comment: One thing that often improves performance much more than it has any right is to use `NDSolveValue` instead of `NIntegrate`.